# How to make helm work on windows 10 , and Docker desktop (Linux container)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I am not able to use Helm and Draft could you please help me.
When I use helm ls , it gives error attached as snap.
I am new to it, so please give step by step guidance, I will be very grateful to you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please delete the screen shots from your question.  Instead, include a [mcve] describing what you’ve already done, including any relevant source files, commands, and error messages, _as text_.  Screen shots of your IDE are very difficult for other people to try to run or understand and can’t be easily searched for later.

Comment: That having been said it looks like you just don’t have Helm installed.

Comment: How to install helm, i tried downloading helm binaries from https://github.com/helm/helm/releases, which have exe for windows. What i need to do next????

Answer (score 1):

Appears you need to install helm to work with Visual Studio.

See the [following](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=technosophos.vscode-helm)

[image]

Else, check the [helm install guide](https://helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#installing-helm) for instructions on setting up helm on your local machine